# isInstanceOf working with path dependent type

Tags: scala

I have following code:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner 
}

val outer1 = new Outer
val outer2 = new Outer
val a1 = new outer1.Inner
val a2 = new outer2.Inner

val a2: outer2.Inner = a1
println(a1.isInstanceOf[outer2.Inner])
```

I know that `val a2: outer2.Inner = a1` has compiling error because of path dependent type, but I don't understand why `println(a1.isInstanceOf[outer2.Inner])` will print `true`

Comment: thats because both a1 and a2 are pointing to the same location of Outer.Inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `outer1.Inner` and `outer2.Inner` have the same erasure, which is written as `Outer#Inner` in Scala. `isInstanceOf` only works up to type erasure unless specified differently for a specific case (as it is for compound types).

This is similar to `List("a", "b").isInstanceOf[List[Int]]` being true: don't trust `isInstanceOf` unless you understand how type erasure works!